# How to call methods of class from inside extended ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to create a custom `ArrayList` that can get multiple types like `ArrayList<A>`, `ArrayList<B>`.

I extended ArrayList like this:

```
public class ArrayListId<E> extends ArrayList {
    public ArrayListId(@NonNull Collection c) {
        super(c);
    }

    public void doSomething(){
        //some code
        String id = this.get(0).getId();
        //some code
}
```

both `A` and `B` have the `getId` method in common but `this.get(index)` returns an `Object` which doesn't have this method so I get an error. how can i achieve this without abstracting `A` and `B` classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there's no need to extend `ArrayList` here. You can do this just fine without using inheritance.

To access the `getId`-method from `A` and `B`, they would need to implement a common interface that defines the method. Something like this:

```java
interface CommonInterface {
    String getId();
}

class A implements CommonInterface { /* implement getId() */ }
class B implements CommonInterface { /* implement getId() */ }
```

With this, you can create an `ArrayList<CommonInterface>` that can contain both As and Bs.

```java
List<CommonInterface> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new A());
list.add(new B());
```

You can take this list as an input to a `doSomething`-method:

```java
public void doSomething(List<CommonInterface> list) {
    //some code
    String id = list.get(0).getId();
    //some code
}
```

If you still need to extend `ArrayList` (you really shouldn't), then you would need to define it like this:

```java
public class ArrayListId<E extends CommonInterface> extends ArrayList<E> {}
```

Comment: Just as a note: `ArrayListId extends ArrayList<CommonInterface>` may also be possible. It really depends on the use case. I.e. whether you ever want a `ArrayListId<A>` or something like that